# For Looping Subplots with Datashader / Holoviews / Bokeh

Tags: python, dataframe, bokeh, holoviews, datashader

The general notation for creating subplots with datashade/holoviews/Bokeh is using a '+' notation:

```
plot = plot1 + plot2 + plot3
```

However, I'm trying to generate plots inside a for loop like I can with Matplotlib. In Seaborn I can just do this to create subplots while incrementing through the dataframe:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(DF_cols), ncols=1, figsize=(10,10), sharex = True)

count = 0
for i in DF_cols:
     sns.lineplot(data=df[i], label=i, ax=axes[count])
     count += 1

return fig, axes
```

How do convert the method I have below for Datashade/Holoviews into a more automated process?

```
c1 = hv.Curve(df['T'])
c2 = hv.Curve(df['A'])
c3 = hv.Curve(df['B'])
c4 = hv.Curve(df['C'])
plot1 = dynspread(datashade(c1))
plot2 = dynspread(datashade(c2))
plot3 = dynspread(datashade(c3))
plot4 = dynspread(datashade(c4))
plot = (plot1 + plot2 + plot3 + plot4).cols(1)
plot
```

My initial approach was to use create a custom string to mimic the normal Datashade notation and running exec() on it, but that doesn't work when using inside functions or it encounters other errors eventually.

Answer (score 2):

You can programmatically create layouts by passing a list of elements to `hv.Layout`. In this case, the following line should do the trick:

```
hv.Layout([plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4]).cols(1)
```

Comment: Or, to account for all the code above, `hv.Layout([dynspread(datashade(hv.Curve(df[c]))) for c in ['T','A','B','C']]).cols(1)`.